# Custom functions in Laravel

Tags: php, csv, laravel-5.3

I use Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel package to upload CSV to DB. Before entering data to DB i wanna do some additional checks with the database. Something like Project_id available in the Project table. Where do i write the required checking function. Is it a proper way to write it in the same controller. I have seen some people create folder In app\Example and write function file in it

**UPDATE :**

please let  me know is this a proper way to do
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fS8q_sD1sZM

***This the sample CSV format***

[image]

***This the controller function***

```
public function uploadDealerCSV()
{
        if(Input::hasFile('file')){
            $path = Input::file('file')->getRealPath();
            $data = Excel::load($path, function ($reader) {
                 $reader->ignoreEmpty();
            })->get();


            if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $insert[] = [
                        'project_id' => $value->project_id, 
                        'dealer_bl_code' => $value->bl_code,
                        'reporgroup' => 104,
                        'added_by' => 73,
                        'updated_at' => '2017-08-08 10:34:54', 
                    ];
                }
                if(!empty($insert)){
                    DB::table('cts_project_list')->insert($insert);
                    //dd('Insert Record successfully.');
                }
            }
        }
        return back();
} 

public function testFunction(){

}
```

Comment: Use this link: http://goodheads.io/2015/08/10/how-to-create-custom-helper-functions-in-laravel-5/

Comment: please let  me know is this a proper way to do
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fS8q_sD1sZM